# Move back to where cursor was before typing text

Tags: vim

Can't figure out how to move the cursor back to the position is was at before typing a bunch of text.

Start situation:

```
<Tag>
  <SubTag property="[cursor is here]" value="" />
  <SubTag property="" value="" />
  <SubTag property="" value="" />
</Tag>
```

Hit 'i', and start typing away:

```
<Tag>
  <SubTag property="yakketyyapyap[Esc][cursor is here]" value="" />
  <SubTag property="" value="" />
  <SubTag property="" value="" />
</Tag>
```

Now I want the cursor to go back to where it was in the start situation, ie over the character before the bit of text that was just entered.

Possible solutions, that feel inadeqate:

- search backwards for quotation mark
- hit the b-key a couple of times
- set a mark before editing, and return to marked location
- yi" ('yank all within quotes', but I don't want to yank anything)

Where is says [cursor is here], I mean, 'the cursor is over the character to the left of this sentence'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `'[` and `']` marks delimit the just edited text after leaving insert mode. Therefore, a `` `[ `` takes you back to where the insert started.

Comment: Well, that was akwardly simple.

Answer (score 2):

did you try:

```
`[
```

?

> '[  `[                  To the first character of the previously
>   changed or yanked text.

Answer (score 2):

Vim put automatically a marker :

`'[` to the **line** of the previously yanked text

`` `[ `` to the **character** of the previously yanked text

Answer (score 1):

You can use

CTRL-O : Retrace your movements in file in backwards

and

CTRL-I : Retrace your movements in file in forwards.